# I can't map my command (Apple) key in vim

Tags: macos, vim

I'm having some trouble mapping my apple key in vim.
I know that 'D' is the mapping symbol for the command button, but it doesn't work!

I've tried with: `map! <D-s> <Esc>:w<Enter>`, but it doesn't work!! I'm getting real frustrated - does anyone know why it's not working?

It works with `map! <F2> <Esc>:w<Enter>`

I am using the terminal version: Vi IMproved 7.2 on Snow Leopard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) version can map the command key. I do not believe any other version can (including the terminal version bundled by default with OS X).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can map this key in the terminal version; can you try with gvim?

Comment: okay.. yea I know it works for gvim, but I just really wanted it for the terminal version. Are you sure it's not possible?

Comment: I am not sure at all, but it does not astonish me that you cannot map it in terminal version.